# uninitialized constant after capistrano delpoy:cold - nginx, unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, capistrano

I have setup capistrano for deployment with the exact same config/setup as found in the railscasts Pro episode http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps?view=asciicast.

All of the deploy:check, status and cold tasks run and complete successfully (after some tinkering). However, the app not running and shows the classic "something went wrong" error page. When I check my unicorn.log it shows the error below:

I have tried requiring the module before including it to address threadsafe issues and also autoloading the absolute path in application.rb. Note this all works in development environment.

How can I amend my code to fix this NameError issue?

unicorn.log

```
E, [2013-10-16T04:15:00.313177 #12996] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant AnswersController::Teebox (NameError)
/home/andrew/rails/teebox/releases/20131016032538/app/controllers/answers_controller.rb:5:in `<class:AnswersController>'
/home/andrew/rails/teebox/releases/20131016032538/app/controllers/answers_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

answers_controller.rb

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  load_and_authorize_resource
  require 'teebox/commentable'
  include Teebox::Commentable # Offending line
  ...

end
```

lib/teebox/commentable.rb

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module Teebox::Commentable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_filter :comments
  end

  def comments
    @comment = Comment.new
  end
end
```

application.rb

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/decorators)
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/teebox/commentable.rb)
```

specs:

```
capistrano 2.15.5
rails 3.2.14
ruby 1.9.3-p488
ubuntu 12.04
```

If anyone needs more code just shout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an naming convention which wasn't an issue on Mac but was an issue on a case sensitive Linux box.

I had a `lib/Teebox/commentable.rb` folder structure and was then calling:

`include Teebox::Commentable`.

So I switched this to `lib/teebox/commentable.rb` (Lowercase teebox) and this solved the error.